# How to click the button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have tired to use *xpath* and *css* locator but both unable to click.

Can anyone help to see why the button element is different from the rest?

[Here is the URL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BNQLP21)

Code trial:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='a-autoid-2']")).click();
```

Comment: Why are you unable? Does your script crash? Throw an error? Does it click the wrong thing?

Comment: which button are you trying to click?

Comment: the Qty:1 button, just the element cannot located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is not a `button` element but a `<span>` tag associated with a *DropDown* looking like a `button` due to the presence of *class* attributes `a-button`, `a-button-dropdown` and `a-button-small`.

To click on the desired element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.a-button.a-button-dropdown.a-button-small span.a-dropdown-prompt")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-button a-button-dropdown a-button-small']//span[@class='a-dropdown-label']")).click();
  ```

Comment: this works. so i need combination of locators...still learning and not quite sure how can i get and combine the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below xpath instead, which have the button role rather the parent span.

```
//span[@id='a-autoid-2']//span[@role='button']
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@id='a-autoid-2']//span[@role='button']"}

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to modify the quantity (Qty),
try the below CSS Selector

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#a-autoid-2 span[data-action='a-dropdown-button']")).Click();
```

There is an attribute for that drop down button which is [aria-pressed="false"]. This defaults to 'false' and once clicked the attribute changes to 'true'. Now WebDriver cannot find the Qty drop down as the above locator's attribute is changed. Try to use a fluent wait after your click in your code to fetch the updated DOM attributes.